# what is this thumbs up/down floating button

Tags: support, advertising

I just noticed a floating up/down thumbs button which appears underneath the favourite tags, is this some new feature that has been enabled by accident?

[image]

It doesn't seem to do anything if you select up or down other than it makes the thumb green.

I'm using Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) on Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: @CodyGray OK, I never noticed this before it just seemed weird to me, so this is a bug I guess

Comment: Yup, it's a bug. I deleted my comment because Oded posted the same thing as an answer around the same time. I intentionally hadn't posted it as an answer because I didn't think it was actually an answer—a good answer would explain why the bug occurred (in other words, which ad it was that didn't load for you and why). You'd need a dev for that.

Comment: this is a way to vote for or against [new top bar](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343653/839601)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like an ad didn't load.

All ads have these buttons - it give you a chance to tell us these are relevant/not relevant to you (if you thumb down an ad - it will not be displayed to you anymore or at a much reduced frequency).

Comment: So this is a bug then I suppose

Comment: @EdChum - yes, but causes? Difficult to tell - could be something on our end, on the ad network end, the advertise end or even your ISP or your end (if you have an ad blocker on, or your ISP blocks ads on your behalf).

Comment: Actually it looks like no ads are appearing at my end, I'm in England, I just tried viewing a few questions and the ads are not appearing, also I'm running no ad blockers

Comment: We've had some proxy issues (dropped packets) around the LHR route - though thous should have been routed around by now. For whats its worth - I am in London and can see the ads (need to refresh a few time to get one, but I do see them).

Comment: OK, I'll accept this answer once the time limit allows me, it just looked weird, thanks for the prompt answer